# How can I loop through objects and append it's values to a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, javascript-objects

Aim:
I'm creating a two page website with the homepage a static page and the other a dynamic page.
I have a number of buttons on the homepage.
I also have a list of objects and I want to loop through each list and append it to each button so that on button click the values of the object will display on the dynamic page.

Here are my codes.

HTML.
Homepage

```
<div>
     <p>USA</p>
    <Input type="button" value="View Flag" />
     <p>EU</p>
     <Input type="button" value="View Flag" />
</div>
```

Dynamic Page

```
<div>
   <div class="flag"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript/jQuery

```
//Objects 
var usFlag ={
     name: "USA flag",
     imgURL: "https://photos.com/usa.jpg"
 }

 var euFlag ={
     name: "EU flag",
     imgURL: "https://photos.com/eu.jpg
 }
 $(.'flag').append('<IMG src=' + imgURL+ ' />);
```

so I want that when I click on USA flag button, the dynamic page will show USA flag and vice versa.

Thank you

Comment: seems like a incomplete answer please provide more details and effort you have done till now

Comment: Yes. I have added more info, if you you need more let me know. Thank you

Comment: you missed a closing double quote here => imgURL: "https://photos.com/usa.jpg and imgURL: "https://photos.com/eu.jpg

Comment: @ShoyebSheikh corrected

Comment: use window.location

Answer (score 0):

If those those divs are on the same page you can do this,

```
<div>
     <p>USA</p>
    <Input type="button" id="usa_button" value="View Flag" />
     <p>EU</p>
     <Input type="button" id="eu_button" value="View Flag" />
</div>
<div>
   <div class="flag"></div>
</div>
</a>
<script> 
//Objects 
var usFlag ={
     name: "USA flag",
     imgURL: "https://photos.com/usa.jpg"
 }

 var euFlag ={
     name: "EU flag",
     imgURL: "https://photos.com/eu.jpg"
 }  
jQuery('#usa_button').on('click',function(){
    jQuery('.flag').html('<img src="'+usFlag.imgURL+'">')
})
jQuery('#eu_button').on('click',function(){
    jQuery('.flag').html('<img src="'+euFlag.imgURL+'">')
})
</script>
```

Comment: This works fine, but I want it to get the IMG URL from the object. Because the code in the question is not the real code am using, it's just a simplified version

Answer (score 0):

Just store particular data in localStorage onclick and redirect to another page where you can get that data

```
<div>
  <p>USA</p>
  <Input type="button" value="View Flag" onclick="setDetails('usFlag')" />
  <p>EU</p>
  <Input type="button" value="View Flag" onclick="setDetails('euFlag')" />
</div>


    function setDetails(data) {

      var usFlag = {
        "name": "USA flag",
        "imgURL": "https://photos.com/usa.jpg"
      };

      var euFlag = {
        "name": "EU flag",
        "imgURL": "https://photos.com/eu.jpg"
      };

      if (data == 'usFlag') {
        localStorage.a = JSON.stringify(euFlag);
        console.log(localStorage.a);

      } else if (data == 'euFlag') {
        localStorage.a = JSON.stringify(euFlag);
        console.log(localStorage.a);
      }

     window.location = "dynamicpage.html";
    }
```